# Printing ascii value with character in byte array in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to print the 2 digit hex ascii value of a character but WriteHex keeps printing 8 bits. I am unsure how to fix this. The byte_array contains all characters of what I am trying to print but I need to print their hex value for a hexdump procedure. I am using the Irvine16 library for the WriteHex proc and a self generated library for the WriteChar240 proc.

```
dump_ascii_value PROC

    pushf
    push dx
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx

    mov dh, location_y
    mov dl, second_col_x
    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h


    mov cx, 0
    mov bx, offset byte_array

    top:
    cmp [bx], cx
    jz done

    mov al, 0
    mov ax, WORD ptr [bx]
    call WriteHex
    mov al, 020h
    call WriteChar240
    inc bx
    jmp top


    done:
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop dx
    popf
    ret


dump_ascii_value ENDP
```

'''

Comment: Well, on second read it's unclear what you want. You claim "but keep printing 8 bits" so that's why I thought you wanted 16 bits. But you also say you have a `byte_array` and "print the 2 bit hex ascii value".  So then `mov ax, WORD ptr [bx]` is loading 16 bits, you want `mov al, byte ptr [bx]` instead.

Comment: I am trying to only print the non-zero values of the ascii value. Instead of 0000006C, I want to print just 6C

Comment: It is a trivial problem to fix, but hard to help because we don't have `WriteChar240`, let alone `WriteHex` from Irvine16 (which is also quite unlikely to be set up). I might say try comparing with `48` instead of `0`, though. Also, you can just `cmp` with an integer constant AKA an *immedate*.

Comment: Presumably `WriteHex` writes 32 bits which is already signalling you have something confusing since that is the 32 bit library. Anyway, you can't fix that to not print the leading zeroes. You should convert the bytes to hex yourself and print the 2 characters separately.